# How to Test CSS/HTML/jQuery?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, css, rspec2

How can I test my CSS/HTML and jQuery code like I do with RSpec?

Comment: I think you need to explain your question a bit more. It is not very clear.... So far my answer is "Use a browser..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw https://github.com/nkallen/screw-unit being compared to RSpec, you could give that a try.

Also: they are talking about [Harmony](http://github.com/mynyml/harmony) on [this page](http://tooky.github.com/2010/03/02/exploring-harmony-for-unit-testing-with-rspec.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my opionion, the best tool for testing front-end web code is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Selenium is a scripting tool that allows create automated tests for your web site. You can use it to run your web site in any browser, and simulate actions such as mouse clicks, etc, and test that the results are as expected.

Hope that helps.